# Failed to create PDF using TCPDF library

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf

So i'am trying to create pdf file in codeigniter4 using tcpdf library. and i always encounter this problem.

**Required parameter $currentfont follows optional parameter $isunicode**

this is my controller to print the PDF.

```
public function sendBill(){
        $data = array(
            'cart' => $this->cart
        );

        $html = view('Bill',$data);

        $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

        $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
        $pdf->SetAuthor('Swan Coffee');
        $pdf->SetTitle('Invoice');
        $pdf->SetSubject('Invoice');

        $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
        $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

        $pdf->addPage();

        $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
        $this->response->setContentType('application/pdf');
        $pdf->Output('invoice.pdf', 'I');
    }
```

Comment: which php version? which CI version? thanks.

Comment: @Vickel PHP 8 and Ci v4.1.1.

Comment: it's possible that with a php version <8 this error goes away, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65162844/required-parameter-from-follows-optional-parameter-verbs

Comment: @Vickel ohh u are right. after i change the php version to PHP7 it works. i can now use the tcpdf lib. Thank you so much.

Comment: you find also this tcpdf issue report: https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/issues/222, try tcpdf version 6.3.5.